# ggplot: plot mean values instead of counts

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have the following sample data, which describe how long (`duration`) each respondent in my questionnaire needed to answer each question (`question`) and in which `week` the question was answered (there were several waves of the same questionnaire)

```
n <- 100

data2 <- data.frame(
  question = paste("q", sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE), sep=""),
  week = sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE),
  duration = round(rnorm(n, mean = 15, sd = 5), 0)
)

ggplot(aes(x = week, fill=question), data = data2) + geom_bar(position='stack') +
xlab("Week")
```

But how can I make the same plot with mean durations instead of counts (on the y-axis)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stat_summary` is the usual function for doing the calculations for you:

```
  ggplot(aes(x = week, y = duration, fill=question), data = data2) +
    stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="bar", position = "stack") +
    xlab("Week")
```

[image: cols from stat_summary]

Edit: This changed my practice the other week when I found out what `stat_` layers can do! [Demystifying stat_ layers in ggplot2](https://yjunechoe.github.io/posts/2020-09-26-demystifying-stat-layers-ggplot2)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `dplyr::group_by`like so.

```
data2 %>% 
  group_by(week,question) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(duration)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(week,mean,fill = factor(question))) +
  geom_col()
```

Good luck!